# Facebook login api via https using localhost

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-login

Hello I am trying to connect via login facebook and is give me an error on redirection url step because must have an https domain

the question is how I configure xampp to run https localhost address that
making me able to redirecting to facebook page .

Comment: you need to disable Enforce HTTP option and add `http://localhost` to `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/?locale=es_ES

Comment: Hello I try to disable Enforce HTTP option is enable by default and is required cant disable it  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#https

Comment: the facebook app needs to be in development mode meanwhile HTTPS is disabled. It could be a good idea to create a "development app" for testing purposes, if you cannot deactivate your current app.

Comment: is already in development mode and as i tell you https is required and cant disable it you check that by your self

Answer (score 0):

> On October 6, 2018, all apps will be required to use HTTPS.

[HTTPS Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#https)

You will need to generate a self singed certificate, put in your local server, then open HTTPs port on your server.

Last but not least, you will need to add `https://localhost:{your-port}` in your app Settings (developers.facebook.com)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man is working by configuring **apache** and **vhosts** to run like as https://localhost

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\_project\public"
   ServerName www.website.com 
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

and finally, go to facebook login and add  valid OAuth redirection URL

cheers